# Run haskell gloss GUI using cabal

Tags: user-interface, haskell, cabal, gloss

I am new to haskell and I want to learn how to create GUIs using the haskell platform. I found this tic tac toe example but I can't seem to figure it out how to run it.

https://github.com/DevJac/gloss-tic-tac-toe

I runned Setup.hs, it compiled but nothing happend. Tried cabal run and this is the output:

Package has never been configured. Configuring with default flags. If this
fails, please run configure manually.
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring gloss-tic-tac-toe-0.1.0.0...
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
base ==4.7.*, gloss >=1.9.2.1 && <1.10

Any ideas?

Comment: I am the author of that tic tac toe game. I have updated it so you can build it using stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Here's what I did to get it to compile:

1. First run `cabal install gloss-examples`

It will take a while as it will install a lot of dependencies. These dependencies are also needed for the tic-tac-toe program.

2. Then do this:

   git clone https://github.com/DevJac/gloss-tic-tac-toe
   cd gloss-tic-tac-toe

and change the build-depends stanza in the .cabal file to read:

```
  build-depends:       base       >= 4.7,
                       gloss      >= 1.9.2.1,
                       containers >= 0.5.5.1
```

Basically just remove all upper bounds.

3. Run `cabal build`
4. If the build succeeds, run the executable:

   ```
   ./dist/build/gloss-tic-tac-toe/gloss-tic-tac-toe
   ```

Comment: This returns the same output as cabal run Package has never been configured. Configuring with default flags. If this
fails, please run configure manually.
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring gloss-tic-tac-toe-0.1.0.0...
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
base ==4.7.*, gloss >=1.9.2.1 && <1.10

Comment: What's your Haskell Platform version? If `base` cannot be satisfied it usually means that your Haskell Platform version isn't compatible with the restrictions set forth in the .cabal file.

Comment: ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.3 and in the cabal file:  build-depends:       base       >= 4.7     && < 4.8,
                       gloss      >= 1.9.2.1 && < 1.10,
                       containers >= 0.5.5.1   && < 5.6

Comment: The 'base' package version specified in the .cabal basically says you need an old version of GHC.  This is probably arbitrary and can be safely changes to `base < 5` then build the package.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are quite new to haskell so it is best to install [stack](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/).

Then after the `git clone https://github.com/DevJac/gloss-tic-tac-toe` it is best to make the following changes to the downloaded source:

Delete the `libsrc` folder you won't need it, replace the build depends section of `gloss-tic-tac-toe.cabal` file with the following:

```
  build-depends:       base       >= 4.8     && < 4.9
               ,       gloss
               ,       containers
```

and add the new file `stack.yaml`

```
resolver: lts-5.17
packages:
- '.'
extra-deps:
- gloss-1.10.1.1
- gloss-rendering-1.10.1.1
flags: {}
extra-package-dbs: []
```

This is the full configuration you need - then running

```
$ > stack build
... (might take some time)
$ > stack exec -- gloss-tic-tac-toe
```

will run the game and you can play!

Comment: stack exec -- gloss-tic-tac-toe
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-5.17 from implicit global project's config file: C:\Users\Rares\AppData\Roaming\stack\global-project\stack.yaml
Executable named gloss-tic-tac-toe not found on path: (my system path variable)

Comment: you are doing the `stack exec ..` inside the cloned `gloss-tic-tac-toe` folder?